Invalid Signature when Signing Multiple Pages and Protecting PDFs in Java
Problem Description
I am developing a desktop application in Java using Swing for digitally signing and protecting PDF files. I have implemented three functionalities:
Sign PDF: Select a PDF file and add a digital signature to the first, last, or all pages.
Sign & Protect PDF: Select a PDF file, add a digital signature along with a password extracted from the file name, to the first, last, or all pages.
Protect PDF: Add a password extracted from the file name to the selected PDF.
Issues
Sign PDF:

When adding a signature to either the first page or the last page,
the signature is valid.
When adding a signature to all pages, the
signature appears as invalid.

Sign & Protect PDF:

When adding a signature to either the first page, last page, or all
pages and then protecting the PDF, the signatures become invalid.

For signing the PDF on multiple pages, I split the PDF into
individual pages in-memory, sign each page, and then merge them back.
For signing and protecting, I first sign the PDF and then apply
password protection.


My expectation is that the signatures should remain valid when signing all pages or when applying both signing and password protection.
Here is the relevant part of my code for signing and protecting PDFs:
private void finishProcess(boolean isProtectionOnly, String pageOption) throws java.io.IOException {
        if (pdfFiles.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No file or folder selected!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        if (destinationFolder == null) {
            File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
            if (isProtectionOnly) {
                destinationFolder = new File(desktop, "Protected_PDFs");
            } else if ("SignPDF".equals(currentProcessType)) {
                destinationFolder = new File(desktop, "Signed_PDFs");
            } else if ("SignProtectPDF".equals(currentProcessType)) {
                destinationFolder = new File(desktop, "SignProtected_PDFs");
            }
            if (!destinationFolder.exists()) {
                destinationFolder.mkdirs();
            }
        }

        if (!isProtectionOnly) {
            signaturePassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter the password for the digital signature:");
            if (signaturePassword == null || signaturePassword.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Password is required to sign the PDF.");
                return;
            }
        }

        for (File file : pdfFiles) {
            if (isProtectionOnly) {
                String password = extractPassword(file);
                if (password != null) {
                    try {
                        addPasswordProtection(file, password, destinationFolder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to add password to " + file.getName(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No valid password found in file name for " + file.getName(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    if ("SignProtectPDF".equals(currentProcessType)) {
                        String protectionPassword = extractPassword(file);
                        if (protectionPassword != null) {
                            signAndProtectPdf(file, pageOption, signaturePassword, protectionPassword);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No valid password found in file name for " + file.getName(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        signPdf(file, pageOption, signaturePassword);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to sign " + file.getName() + "\n" + e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("PDF's Successfully Processed!");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, panel, "Successful", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "MainScreen");

        model.setRowCount(0);
        selectedPathField.setText("");
        pdfFiles.clear();
        destinationFolder = null;
    }

    private String extractPassword(File file) {
        String baseName = file.getName();
        String[] nameParts = baseName.split("_");
        if (nameParts.length > 1) {
            return nameParts[nameParts.length - 1].replace(".pdf", "");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String extractBaseFileName(File file) {
        String baseName = file.getName();
        int lastUnderscoreIndex = baseName.lastIndexOf('_');
        if (lastUnderscoreIndex != -1) {
            return baseName.substring(0, lastUnderscoreIndex) + ".pdf";
        }
        return baseName;
    }

    private void addPasswordProtection(File file, String password, File destinationFolder) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
        StandardProtectionPolicy protectionPolicy = new StandardProtectionPolicy(password, password, null);
        protectionPolicy.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
        protectionPolicy.setPermissions(new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission());
        document.protect(protectionPolicy);

        String outputFileName = extractBaseFileName(file);
        File outputFile = new File(destinationFolder, outputFileName);
        document.save(outputFile);
        document.close();
    }

private void signPdf(File file, String pageOption, String password) throws Exception {
        if (selectedCertificateAlias == null) {
            throw new Exception("No certificate alias selected.");
        }

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        ks.load(null, null);

        KeyStore.PasswordProtection passwordProtection = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(selectedCertificateAlias, passwordProtection);
        if (pkEntry == null) {
            throw new Exception("No key found for alias: " + selectedCertificateAlias);
        }

        PrivateKey pk = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
        Certificate[] chain = pkEntry.getCertificateChain();
        if (chain == null) {
            throw new Exception("No certificate chain found for alias: " + selectedCertificateAlias);
        }

        IExternalSignature pks = new MSCAPISignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
        IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

        if ("All Pages".equals(pageOption)) {
            // Split the PDF into individual pages in-memory
            List<byte[]> singlePageFiles = splitPdfInMemory(file);

            List<byte[]> signedPageFiles = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < singlePageFiles.size(); pageIndex++) {
                byte[] singlePageFile = singlePageFiles.get(pageIndex);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(singlePageFile));
                PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, writer, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

                try {
                    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
                    appearance.setReason("Testing")
                            .setLocation("Location")
                            .setPageRect(new Rectangle(350, 40, 200, 100))
                            .setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION)
                            .setPageNumber(1);

                    String fieldName = "Signature" + (pageIndex + 1);
                    signer.setFieldName(fieldName); // Ensure unique field names

                    signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
                } finally {
                    reader.close();
                    writer.close();
                }
                signedPageFiles.add(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            }

            // Merge the signed pages back into a single PDF in-memory
            File signedPdfFile = new File(destinationFolder, extractBaseFileName(file));
            mergePdfsInMemory(signedPageFiles, signedPdfFile);
        } else {
            try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
                 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFolder, extractBaseFileName(file)))) {
                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance()
                        .setReason("Testing")
                        .setLocation("Location")
                        .setPageRect(new Rectangle(350, 40, 200, 100))
                        .setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION)
                        .setCertificate(chain[0]);

                int totalPages = signer.getDocument().getNumberOfPages();

                switch (pageOption) {
                    case "First Page":
                        appearance.setPageNumber(1);
                        signer.setFieldName("sig");
                        signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
                        break;

                    case "Last Page":
                        appearance.setPageNumber(totalPages);
                        signer.setFieldName("sig");
                        signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
                        break;

                    case "Customized Pages":
                        String pageNumbers = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter the page numbers separated by commas:");
                        if (pageNumbers != null && !pageNumbers.trim().isEmpty()) {
                            String[] pageNums = pageNumbers.split(",");
                            for (String pageNum : pageNums) {
                                int pageNumber;
                                try {
                                    pageNumber = Integer.parseInt(pageNum.trim());
                                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid page number: " + pageNum, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (pageNumber > 0 && pageNumber <= totalPages) {
                                    try (PdfReader pageReader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                         FileOutputStream pageOs = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFolder, "signed_page_" + pageNumber + ".pdf"))) {
                                        PdfSigner pageSigner = new PdfSigner(pageReader, pageOs, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
                                        pageSigner.getSignatureAppearance()
                                                .setReason("Testing")
                                                .setLocation("Location")
                                                .setPageRect(new Rectangle(350, 40, 200, 100))
                                                .setPageNumber(pageNumber)
                                                .setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION)
                                                .setCertificate(chain[0]);
                                        pageSigner.setFieldName("sig_" + pageNumber);
                                        pageSigner.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Page number out of range: " + pageNumber, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Unsupported page option: " + pageOption);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<byte[]> splitPdfInMemory(File sourceFile) throws IOException {
        List<byte[]> singlePageFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
             PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
            int totalPages = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
                     PdfDocument singlePageDoc = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
                    pdfDoc.copyPagesTo(i, i, singlePageDoc);
                }
                singlePageFiles.add(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            }
        }
        return singlePageFiles;
    }

    private void mergePdfsInMemory(List<byte[]> files, File destination) throws IOException {
        try (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(destination);
             PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
            PdfPageFormCopier formCopier = new PdfPageFormCopier();
            for (byte[] file : files) {
                try (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(file));
                     PdfDocument tempDoc = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
                    tempDoc.copyPagesTo(1, tempDoc.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDoc, formCopier);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void signAndProtectPdf(File file, String pageOption, String signaturePassword, String protectionPassword) throws Exception {
        // Sign the PDF
        signPdf(file, pageOption, signaturePassword);
        // Apply password protection
        File signedFile = new File(destinationFolder, extractBaseFileName(file));
        addPasswordProtection(signedFile, protectionPassword, destinationFolder);
    }




Yes, I am using both PDFBox and iText in the same application. I am leveraging PDFBox for handling the PDF structure and extracting information, while iText is being used for the digital signing process and adding protection to the PDFs. This approach allows me to utilize the strengths of both libraries to achieve the desired functionality in my application. If you have any insights or recommendations for better integration or handling of these libraries together, I would greatly appreciate it.

Fortunately you described your approach because there is a whole lot of code which would have been difficult to inspect.
Signing and Password Protection

When adding a signature to either the first page, last page, or all pages and then protecting the PDF, the signatures become invalid.

This is to be expected:
When you digitally sign a PDF, in particular a hash is calculated for the bytes of the whole PDF (except the placeholder in which the actual signature container eventually is embedded), and during validation the validator checks whether that hash at validation time is the same as the hash at signing time.
And protecting the PDF essentially means encrypting relevant portions of the PDF and adding encryption metadata.
Thus, when you first sign a PDF and thereafter protect it, that protection step changes the bytes of the PDF and, consequentially, the hash. A validator, therefore, will recognize your signatures as broken, they have become invalid.
If you want to combine signing and encryption, you have to apply encryption no later than in the actual signing step.
Signing and Merging

For signing the PDF on multiple pages, I split the PDF into individual pages in-memory, sign each page, and then merge them back. For signing and protecting, I first sign the PDF and then apply password protection.

This also is to be expected:
As mentioned above, digitally signing a PDF in particular means calculating a hash of the bytes of nearly the whole PDF for later comparison.
And merging PDF does not merely concatenate the individual PDF files in a larger file, it combines their data, e.g. building a single page tree with all pages from all the original page trees with one page each.
Thus, when you sign PDFs and thereafter merge them, the merging step changes the bytes and, consequentially, the hash. A validator, therefore, will recognize your signatures as broken, they have become invalid.
So you cannot merge multiple signed PDFs while keeping the signatures valid.
In this case the question is what your intention is in adding a signature to all pages.

Do you want the integrity of all pages to be protected by digital signatures? In that case a single signature suffices! An integrated PDF signature always hashes the whole revision in which it is added, so a signature validator validates the integrity of the content of all pages, no matter on which there is an image representing that signature.

Do you actually want a signature image on each page of the digitally signed document? In that case apply the digital signature on just one page and in the same step add simple signature images (without a digital signature of their own) to all other pages.

Or do you indeed need a signature widget on each page that can be clicked to open a signature validation dialog. In that case you have to take the whole original document and apply one signature after the other in a loop, each time loading the previous revision of the PDF, creating a PdfSigner, and applying the next signature.



Signing and Password Protection:
I tried protecting the PDF first, then adding the signature, but the signatures became invalid. How can I sign and protect the PDF without invalidating the signatures?
Signing and Merging:
Signature on All Pages:
I need a signature on all pages.
Adding Signature Image:
Adding a signature to one page and images to others changes the PDF structure and hash. How can I preserve the hash value?
Incremental Method:
I tried adding clickable signature widgets on all pages incrementally, but all signatures are invalid. Any guidance?

"Signing and Password Protection: I tried protecting the PDF first, then adding the signature, but the signatures became invalid. How can I sign and protect the PDF without invalidating the signatures?" - There usually is no magic required. you might want to share your code for that approach.

"Adding a signature to one page and images to others changes the PDF structure and hash. How can I preserve the hash value?" - if you add images in the same run as signing (using the PdfDocument from the PdfSigner) or earlier, you don't need to try and preserver the hash value, do you?

"I tried adding clickable signature widgets on all pages incrementally, but all signatures are invalid. Any guidance?" -  I don't see your code, so I don't see what's wrong in it. One guess: Have you remembered to use append mode for adding the signatures?

I have provided the code which i have used above, can you check in that

Your code still has the issues mentioned in my answer.

Sorry, I am not sure, what issues you are referring to as the provided code is completely working fine without any errors. The only issue is with adding signature to all pages of a PDF document.
can you be more specific on the issue that you are referring?

In the case of "All Pages" you still split the PDF, sign each partial page, and merge the signed partial PDFs. As explained in my answer, that cannot work.

Ok, I corrected the Invalid signature issue for "All pages" using incremental update method.
Now, I am having trouble only with Signing and Protecting the PDF,
Should i protect the PDF first and then add signature to the protected PDF?
Or Should i sign and protect the PDF at a time?

I'd try it in one step.

Tired that, it did not work.
I followed this approach.
First i protected the PDF, then opened the protected PDF using required password and later i added the signature and it worked.
Thanks a lot for your inputs, it helped a lot
